# Tag synonym/merge needed: [certificate] [certificates] [digital-certificates]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The following tags should be made synonymous:

- [certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/certificate) (most current uses)
- [certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/certificates)
- [digital-certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digital-certificate)

These additional tags are more specific and may or may not be worth keeping distinct:

- [ssl-certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssl-certificate)
- [x509certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x509certificate) (note existing tag wiki)
- [x509certificate2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x509certificate2)
- [root-certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/root-certificate)

I do not have the tag score to propose any of these synonyms myself or I would do so already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 years and 10 months later, the 3 tags are synonymized.

[certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/certificate) <- [certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/certificates) was created by [Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372643/bruno) on Jul 15 '14 at 0:55.

I have now synonymized [digital-certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/digital-certificate) -> [certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/certificate). Both the tags had the same (plagiarized) tag wiki about certificates used in cryptography, therefore it made complete sense to merge them both.